# Is there an intuitive way to loop through multiprocessing.Connection object until EOF is reached?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am developing a tool to scrape tweets and process them in order to build a word frequency analysis by user. Due to the sheer volume of the data needed to be processed, I am splitting the word processing section away from the tweet scraping section.

[`multiprocessing.Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection) (`rec, sen = multiprocessing.Pipe(False)`) provides a useful utility to transfer data between processes. However, I cannot find a utility that the receiving end may tell when EOF has been reached when the sending end explicitly calls `Connection.close()`. I attempted:

```
def yielder(conn):
    yield conn.recv()
```

but this somehow stops after returning only the first item in the pipe.
I am currently bypassing the problem with a Try-Except statement inside a `while True` loop:

```
try:
    status = rec.recv()
    ...process data...
except BrokenPipeError:
    break
```

I can also see this be done through sending a specific end marker and let the receiving end terminate the process when it receives that. But those are very counter-intuitive and ugly ways to do it, violating the Zen of Python:

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> ...
>
> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Am I missing something? Is there a simple, elegant way like c++'s

```
while getline(istreamobject, line)
```

to perform my task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second form of calling [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter): `iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator` to make it into a for loop. You still would have to catch the exception though.

```
try:
    for status in iter(conn.recv, None):
        ...
except BrokenPipeError:
    pass
```

If instead of closing the pipe, you send an "eof" down the pipe, you can remove the `try/except` and do `for status in iter(conn.recv, 'EOF message')`, and when `'EOF message'` is recieved (can be anything), `iter` stops the for loop. Usually the EOF message is an empty string, so it is common to see things like:

```
for line in iter(file.read, ''):
    ...
```

---

The [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) have this function called `iter_except`. This is basically what you wanted to do before with the `yielder` function

```
def iter_except(func, exception, first=None):
    """ Call a function repeatedly until an exception is raised.

    Converts a call-until-exception interface to an iterator interface.
    Like builtins.iter(func, sentinel) but uses an exception instead
    of a sentinel to end the loop.

    Examples:
        iter_except(functools.partial(heappop, h), IndexError)   # priority queue iterator
        iter_except(d.popitem, KeyError)                         # non-blocking dict iterator
        iter_except(d.popleft, IndexError)                       # non-blocking deque iterator
        iter_except(q.get_nowait, Queue.Empty)                   # loop over a producer Queue
        iter_except(s.pop, KeyError)                             # non-blocking set iterator

    """
    try:
        if first is not None:
            yield first()            # For database APIs needing an initial cast to db.first()
        while True:
            yield func()
    except exception:
        pass
```

So, you could also do something like this:

```
for status in iter_except(conn.recv, BrokenPipeError):
    ...
```

Or just fixing the `yielder` function:

```
def yielder(conn):
    try:
        while True:
            yield conn.recv()
    except BrokenPipeError:
        pass

for status in yielder(conn):
    ...
```

Comment: The yielder function does't throw any exception. it simply yields the first value in pipe then stop.

Comment: @flymousechiu Did it still only yield the first value without the `while True` loop?

Comment: yes, as evident if you try the following: `import multiprocessing as mp`, `def yielder(conn): yield conn.recv()`, `rec, sen = mp.Pipe(False)`, `for i in range(10): sen.send(i)`, `list(yielder(rec))`. should return [0]